# Change "hello world from section: 1"

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am begginer on android.

when I create new activity, I choose Tabbed Activity.

How to change a "Hello world from section: 1" into difference String value on every slide.

This is part of my main class:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it in `PlaceholderFragment`. In this demo app, you will notice that in the method `PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);`. The position is passed to the `Fragment` and on its basis the text is set to the `TextView` in it.

You can write a switch case for each position in the `newInstance()` method and change the text to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is my way of doing things, I think it's quite inefficient but it works

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
    textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));


    int NumberOfArguments;
    NumberOfArguments = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);

    //inicio

    switch (NumberOfArguments) {
        case 1:
            // CREATE TEXTVIEW IN fragment_main ID: mesagge  //Change number of tabs in the end of the MainActivity in: public int getcount{}  - return 
            View rootView2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView2 = (TextView) rootView2.findViewById(R.id.mesagge);
            textView2.setText("This ");
            return rootView2;

        case 2:
            View rootView3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView3 = (TextView) rootView3.findViewById(R.id.mesagge);
            textView3.setText("Is A");
            return rootView3;

        case 3:
            View rootView4 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView4 = (TextView) rootView4.findViewById(R.id.mesagge);
            textView4.setText("Good Time");
            return rootView4;

        case 4:
            View rootView5 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView5 = (TextView) rootView5.findViewById(R.id.mesagge);
            textView5.setText("TO Learn");
            return rootView5;


        case 5:
            View rootView6 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView6 = (TextView) rootView6.findViewById(R.id.mesagge);
            textView6.setText("Code");
            return rootView6;

    }

    return rootView;
}
```